# Excel VBA Saves as a 2019/19 File type when using Save As function (but only sometimes)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble figuring out why Excel is saving a file as a 2019/19 file type, example in link below

[image]

The macro I'm writing is a simple `SaveAs` function, pasted below

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="FilePathICan'tShareBecauseWork" & name & "", FileFormat:=51, Password:="AlsoCan'tShareBecausePrivacy"
```

name is a variable which gains an input from the user using msgbox, it only does this sometimes and everytime I have run the code myself, it only saves as an excel workbook (not macro enabled). Any ideas?

Comment: Because `FileFormat:=51` means *"not macro enabled"*. Read [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) and [xlFileFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat). • That's all we can say until you [edit] your question and share the relevant code parts or a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I actually was able to solve the problem, I was using periods in the file name which was causing the file extension to change to the string after the last period. So instead of using periods for the date I used dashes instead